# While loop and innerHTML - Why does it show the numbers in reverse?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, innerhtml

```
function doItAgain() {

            var loopCount = 5;

            while(loopCount > 0) {

                    var target = document.getElementById("target");
                    target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;
                    console.log("LoopCount is now: " + loopCount);
                    loopCount = loopCount -1;
                }
```

Here's the present function.
It's activated by a button defined with the onclick event handler.

Now, my question is the following -> why does it show, once the button is pressed the numbers from 1 to 5 and not from 5 to 1 like in the console?
I already know that if I set target.innerHTML to the start of the sentence that it will show them from 5 to 1 in my web page but I can't figure out why is that

Comment: Walk through it in your head or on paper. You're adding to the front of the string, so you're pushing the first added numbers down.

Comment: change `target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;` to `target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML; + "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>"`

Comment: ^^ It's also well worth your time to learn, right at the beginning, how to use the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE. Then you can single-step through the code, statement-by-statement, and see exactly what the variables contain at any given moment, what the order of operations you're doing is, etc.

Comment: Briefly I thought of that as the solution to my question but it flew away and I just couldn't get it again. Thanks for the clarification, @Carcigenicate

Comment: You prepend the new data from each iteration, ie the later the iteration comes the more distant from the end of the string it will be placed, being equivalent to 'the closer to the start of the string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what this line does:

```js
target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;
```

Let's say that `target.innerHTML`, after the first loop, contains

```html
LoopCount: 5<br>
```

Then on the `loopCount = 4` loop, you're doing

```js
target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;
```

again, which is

```
target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + "LoopCount: 5<br>";
// -----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and so you get

```html
LoopCount: 4<br>LoopCount: 5
```

and so on.

If you put the `innerHTML` *first* on that line, you'll reverse the order:

```
target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + "<br>LoopCount: " + loopCount;
```